# How do I run two commands as part of a single docker-compose "command"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, docker, docker-compose

I’m using Docker v. 20.10.12.  I have set up this container in my docker-compose file …

```
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./my-web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    expose:
      - '3000'
    env_file: ./my-web/.docker_env
    command: rm -f /app/tmp/pids/*.pid && foreman start -f Procfile.hot
    volumes:
    - ./my-web/:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
```

When I start using “docker-compose up”, the above container always displays this message

```
my-web-1 exited with code 0
```

There is no other info before that.  However, if I change the command to be

```
command: tail -F anything
```

And then log in to the docker container, I can run

```
rm -f /app/tmp/pids/*.pid && foreman start -f Procfile.hot
```

just fine without an errors.  How would I run that as part of starting up my Docker container without having to do the manual steps from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
command: /bin/sh -c "rm -f /app/tmp/pids/*.pid && foreman start -f Procfile.hot"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all your commands inside an external sh file.
in docker-compose use

command: /bin/sh -c "yourshfile.sh"

Comment: I tried a variation of taht, using "command: /bin/bash -c start.sh", but it gives the error "/bin/bash: start.sh: command not found"